# Rest service slow download

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

My current working rest service for downloading a file is very slow and I'm trying to find a better implementation to improve download speed. The problem is that I have 2 servers (client and storage) and they communicate only with serialization objects so for example I can't pass Resource object from client to storage and vice versa. The actual file is located on my storage service.Currently when there is a request for download client server receive a byte[] array and create an OutputStream. Is there some other approach that will work with serialization classes?
This is my current client rest service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {

    byte[] imgbytes = null;

    imgbytes  = fileService.getFullFile(fileName);
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.write(imgbytes, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        logger.error("IO ERROR - ", ioException);
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error closing stream - ", e);
        }
        }
    }
    }
```